# AEM "Fourceunpublish" button need to disabled or delete

Tags: osgi, aem, aem-6, crx

I need to disable to `Force Unpublish` button in AEM site.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq3h0.png)

Scenario : When I'm unpublishing a page in AEM site that is liked to another parent page AEM will show OOTB `Force Unpublish` option as in the picture in the above.How do i disable "Force Unpublish" button?.

I tred to figureout this popup in AEM crx/de. Finally I found below link,
`/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/pageinfo/confirmunpublish/confirmunpublish.jsp`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNiYl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l84P.png)
Once i `Confirm` it's calling `confirmAttrs.build()` however
I'm not able to figureout `Force Unpublish` button .jsp file or anything that relate to source of this popup.
Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, where "Force Unpublish" button available in AEM 6.5 v,

```
/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/editors/clientlibs/core/js/actions/unpublish.js
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).